# Trouble with Magento Module name in Parallel plesk. Issue seems like with Case sensitivity

Tags: php, magento, module, case-sensitive, plesk

I am having a trouble with my Magento module name in parallel Plesk. My module's name is like `ComPany/MYMODULE`  and it works fine in `localhost`.

But i uploaded it to a live server in Parallel plesk, I m getting error such as `Source model "mymodule/entity_attribute_source_yesnodefault" not found for attribute "mymodule_update_images"`

It seems case sensitivity plays the role here. So I changed the MYMODULE folder to mymodule and changed `ComPany/mymodule/etc/config.xml` appropriately. But no use! Still the local works fine and Live server gives the error!

How can I overcome this error? If you have any Idea, share...

Answer (score 2):

Magento has a convention you should follow if you are not an expert developer.

Module name should be in CamelCase, first letter should be capital and rest should be in smallcase. If you have module name in more than one word, instead of space just capital the next word's first character and append to the first word.

Example:

> Module name = My module name
>
> Magento Convention = MyModuleName

I would suggest to rename your namespace and module name
from ComPany_MYMODULE to MyCompany_MyModule
to prevent misunderstanding..